# Tkinter widgets not showing

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm a beginner and just getting into Tkinter basics. I'm following along with a tutorial, but none of my widgets are appearing in the window. No errors.

```
import Tkinter

class pinger(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

def initialize(self):
    self.grid()



    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Button")
    button.grid(column=1,row=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = pinger(None)
    app.title('Server Pinger')
    app.mainloop()
```

The window opens without an issue and no errors are shown. The button widget is nowhere to be found, nor is any other widget I try.

Comment: Can you please first fix your indentation. And then also update us what you were expecting to see , and what else are you seeing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that according to the indentation the function - initialize() - is outside the class . Also even if the function was inside the class , you never really call it .

In Python, indentation is really important , it is used for defining blocks . Also , you should call the initialize() function inside your **init**() function . Example -

```
import Tkinter

class pinger(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Button")
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = pinger(None)
    app.title('Server Pinger')
    app.mainloop()
```